Boton no funciona en modo responsive
Estoy creando una aplicación en python con Django. Tengo un view donde se muestran datos de los movimientos de una cuenta y para mostrarlos he utilizado el plugin de Datables. El problema viene cuando se carga la página en pantallas pequeñas... El responsive funciona perfectamente pero el botón del formulario deja de funcionar...
Tengo el código del template así:
        <div class="card-body">
          <table id="movs" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Data moviment</th>
                <th>Concepte moviment</th>
                <th>Imports</th>
                <th>Saldo</th>
                <th>Cat</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for item in object_list %}
                <tr style="background-color:{{ item.categoria_moviment.color_categoria }}">
                    <form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
                        <td>{{ item.data_moviment }}</td>
                        <td>
                            <input name="concepte" class="form-control input-lg" type="text" value="{{ item.concepte_moviment }}">
                        </td>
                        {% if item.import_moviment < 0 %}
                            <td style = "color:red">{{ item.import_moviment|floatformat:"2g" }}€</td>
                        {% else %}
                            <td style = "color:green">{{ item.import_moviment|floatformat:"2g" }}€</td>
                        {% endif %}
                        <td>{{ item.saldo_moviment|floatformat:"2g" }}€</td>
                        <td>                               
                            <input type="hidden" name="id_moviment" value="{{ item.id_moviment}}" />
                            <select name="id_categoria">                                               
                                {% for cat in categories %}
                                    {% if item.categoria_moviment.id_categoria != cat.id_categoria %}
                                        <option value="{{ cat.id_categoria }}" />{{ cat.nom_categoria }}</option>
                                    {% else %}
                                        <option value="{{ cat.id_categoria }}" selected="{{ cat.nom_categoria}}" />{{ cat.nom_categoria}}</option>
                                    {% endif %}
                                {% endfor %}
                            </select>
                            <button type="submit" name="ok">OK</button>
                        </td>
                    </form>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <th>Data moviment</th>
                <th>Concepte moviment</th>
                <th>Imports</th>
                <th>Saldo</th>
                <th>Cat</th>
            </tr>
            </tfoot>
          </table>
        </div>

La tabla y el formulario funcionan bien y al cargarse en una pantalla de tamaño reducido como un móvil también se carga bien. El problema aparece con el boton Ok del formulario que cuando la pantalla es pequeña no guarda los cambios hechos en la fila de la tabla. He estado mirando la documentació de Datatables pero no encuentro donde puede estar el error...
El código de javascript para cargar la tabla es este:
   <script>
        $(function () {
          $('#movs').DataTable({
            "paging": true,
            "lengthChange": false,
            "searching": false,
            "ordering": false,
            "info": false,
            "autoWidth": false,
            "responsive": true,
          });
          
        });
    </script>

Alguna idea de donde puede estar el error? Muchas gracias!

Usa inspeccionar y revisa si el boton pierde algun atributo o clase cuando la pantalla es mas pequeña
